# .Rprofile not found in working directory despite adding newline

Tags: r, install.packages

I have tried a number of different configurations, and just don't have the time to keep looking through examples. I saw this thread [.Rprofile not sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686292/rprofile-not-sourced) and hoped it would have the answer. The problem might be because I am working on a Windows system and it seemed that posting referred to a Mac OS. I have an R project and in the **same working directory** I tried adding the ".Rprofile.txt" file. I have tried the following syntax: "Rprofile", "RProfile", ".Rprofile", and ".RProfile". I have been able to run the file using `source()` and that seemed to work. In the link above, it mentioned needing the trailing newline character. I tried that on a separate line, at the end of the script, and at the end of the script with a space. I cannot figure out what the nuance is that I am not picking up. Can someone please help? This is my script:

```
print("The stringsAsFactors have been disabled. We are loading some common libraries")
suppressMessages(require(xlsxjars))
suppressMessages(require(xlsx))
suppressMessages(require(purrr))
suppressMessages(require(crayon)) \n
```

Lastly, I insterted the `print()` statement so I could see if the script was being picked up. That isn't happening. *Thanks for your help in advance, and I am sorry, but without examples the other postings don't quite fix the problem.*

Comment: On Windows it's `Rprofile.site`, in the `etc` folder.

Comment: One last note; I tried running ```options("defaultPackages"=pkgs)``` and that was after installing the packages that were added to the string of "pkgs". Such packages were those like "purrr" or "xlsx" and I still didn't see those added after specifying. Maybe there is some odd configuration I need to set up?

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you, but can't you create a specific "Rprofile" in the same working directory that will override the "Home" directory? I tried using "Rprofile.site" in the naming convention just now, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I was fortunate enough to find the answer here [How to access and edit Rprofile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819684/how-to-access-and-edit-rprofile) and when I ran the `file.edit(".Rprofile")` and was able to add the .Rprofile script in the source window. Thanks @Rui Barradas for the tip, it helped me find the answer. I noticed after saving in the source window, an actual .Rprofile file was saved in the working directory. This can always be edited with `file.edit()`.