# knitr not sourcing project .Rprofile properly when rendering

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a Rstudio project set up with the .Rprofile containing

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.path='cache/', fig.path='figures/')
```

I separately have a .Rmd file in a subdirectory when I render into a html. However, it appears that .Rprofile is not sourced at all until I directly source it using `source(here('.Rprofile'))`. I do know that it is sourced properly in the console, and I'd like the knitr render process to source it to (without me directly doing it). What is going on? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you ran in the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686292/rprofile-not-sourced

Comment: I did see that issue and added some newlines and changed the User option that appends the newline and it still didn't render.

Comment: Hm. Works fine when I add your chunk to my .Rprofile and knit a simple rmd.

Comment: Is your Rmd in the same directory as the .Rprofile? I have it in a subdirectory in the same project.

Comment: Okay. I first tried on my default .Rprofile. So. In that case everything is fine. However, when I put your chunk in an .Rprofile in the project dir it only gets loaded when it is in the same dir as the rmd. Hm. So at least I could replicate the problem. (;

Comment: haha at least I'm not going crazy! I thought .Rprofiles were automatically sourced wherever in the project dir but maybe that's not the case?

Comment: (: The issue is probably that by default the working dir of a Rmd document is the dir where the rmd is located. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/working-directory.html . When setting the default wd as the project dir in the Rstudio options the .Rprofile is found and executed. But not sure wether this is an option for you.

Comment: I changed to knitr directory to the project directory and it seems to run. However, it doesn't seem to change the knitr options... 
`print(knitr::opts_chunk$get('cache.path'))` gave the default. I think I am going to give up on using .Rprofile to change knitr options and do it as a separate source script...

Answer (score 1):

When you click the knit button in Rstudio, it launches a separate R session to compile the document [(source)](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/notebook.html#executing-code) and this process occurs in the directory the .Rmd file is located. If that directory is not your project root (i.e. where your .Rprofile is), the .Rprofile is not being properly sourced. To source it, add this at the top of your .Rmd:

```
source("../.Rprofile", chdir = TRUE)
```